# Stack implementation C++

Tags: c++, stack

I have implemented a stack using the next class:

```
template <typename T, int lungime> class Depou
{
    private:

        T *depouarray;
        int top;

    public:

        Depou ()
        {
            this -> top = -1;
            depouarray = (T *) calloc (lungime, sizeof (T));

        }

        ~Depou ()
        {
            free (depouarray);
        }

        void push (T x)
        {
            if (top >= lungime - 1)
            {
                return;
            }

            top ++;
            depouarray [top] = x;   
        }

        T pop ()
        {
            if (isEmpty ())
            {
                return -1;
            }
            T x;
            x = depouarray [top];
            top --;
            return x;   
        }

        T peek ()
        {
            if (isEmpty ())
            {
                return -1;
            }
            return depouarray[top];
        }

        int isEmpty ()
        {
            return (top < 0);
        }
}
```

My problem is the next one:
After I've added an element to the stack, let's say 3, I verified it and it showed 3.
Next, I added another element, let's say 4, I verified the content of the stack and it showed a very high number (which is surely junk) and 4. I cannot understand why it transforms the first elements into junk, leaving only the last element added as it should be.

Comment: This is C++. Why are you doing manual memory allocations?

Comment: `std::stack` not working for you?

Comment: Why are you using `calloc` and `free` in C++?

Comment: I have to implement my own stack, with a limited capacity, and I must allocate it dynamically.

Comment: I just tried out your class and did not get any garbage in the stack after pushing 3, then 4. Please provide more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my colleague pointed out, you have many errors within your code and I think i t would be too much effort to correct it.  Hence I'm giving you a stack implementation.

A stack is a FILO structure.  The best way to implement it is to use Node and to link them together.  Look at the code below, it is straight forward.  Let me know if you have questions.

```
template <class T>
class Stack {
public:
    Stack();
    ~Stack();
    void push(const T&);
    void pop(T& out);
    T pop();
    bool is_empty() const;
    void clear();
private:
    class Node {
    public:
        Node(const T& t, Node* c);
        T contain;
        Node* next;
    };
    Node* peak;
```

};

```
template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack()
{
    peak = NULL;
}

template <class T>
Stack<T>::~Stack()
{
    clear();
}

template <class T>
bool Stack<T>::is_empty() const
{
    return peak == NULL;
}

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::clear()
{
    while(!is_empty())
        pop();
}

template <class T>
Stack<T>::Node::Node(const T& t, Node* c) : next(c)
{
    contain = t;
}

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push(const T& t)
{
    peak = new Node(t, peak);
    assert(peak);
}

template <class T>
T Stack<T>::pop()
{
    assert(peak);
    Node c(*peak);
    delete peak;
    peak = c.next;
    return c.contain;
}

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::pop(T& t)
{
    assert(peak != NULL);
    t = peak->contain;
    Node* c = peak;
    peak = peak->next;
    delete c;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I do have a question. What is assert(peak) in pop and push functions meant to do?

Comment: assert(peak) is the same thing as assert(peak != NULL), actually the last form is better because it explicity says peak is a pointer.
It serves as a post condition.  It says that after pushing an element in, peak shouldn't be null
The same thing happens with pop.  It verifies that peak is a valid pointer before removing the element.
You should use assert to prevent undefined behavior from the programmer.  That way you(programmer) cannot use pop when the stack as no element in it.

Comment: You are welcome.  If you think the issue is solved, you may vote for my answer.

Comment: How can you delete a node in function pop() and then refer to the same node ? it seems like you first make c to point to the same location peak points and then you delete peak, and then you try to access it ...